# Google non-keyed requests on third-party sites and apps

Tags: image, google-maps, email, outlook.com

I have a static map image using the standard google maps url with no api key.

This appears to work for every email client, except recently for outlook.live.com.

[Example](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=39.097389221191400,-84.262458801269500&maptype=roadmap%5C&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7C39.097389221191400,-84.262458801269500&zoom=10&size=248x145)

Instead of the expected image, I get a gray jpg with "g.co/staticmaperror/key" written across it, which leads to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/error-messages#key).

I know Google limits the use to 25,000 per day for non-keyed requests. Is this simply Google recognizing the request limit for outlook.live.com? If so, why haven't I seen this behavior on other clients, such as Yahoo mail? Or how do they measure things like me opening the email in my desktop Outlook mailbox?

Comment: Maybe outlook.live.com wasn't "grandfathered" by Google? The API key is [mandatory](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) for new domains after June 22, 2016.